# live calculation for popup page

Tags: javascript, php

I m developing my own supermarket website, 
i have working live calcuation script took from webiste, if applied in my popup page to do live calculation eg: 1kg rice($200) x 2 quantity = 400$.
this concept applied in this page, its not working.
please send help me on this.
basically i need live calcuating based on quanty and kg selection .

```js
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#size').change(function() {
    updateValues();
});

$('#qty').keyup(function() {
    updateValues();
});

function updateValues(){
    // Remove any previously set values
    $('#show_box, #total_box').empty();
    var qty =  document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var price = 0;
    var rate = 0;    
    $('#size').find('option:selected').each(function() {
        // Check that the attribute exist, so that any unset values won't bother
        if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {             
            price = $(this).data('price');
            rate = price*qty;
            $('#show_box').append('<h6>' + rate + '</h6>');
        }
    });
    $('#total_box').text(rate);
}    </script>
```

```html
<!--==================================
  Quick view modal window
======================================-->

<div id="quick_view" class="modal_window">

 <button class="close arcticmodal-close"></button>

 <div class="clearfix">

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product image column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <div class="single_product">

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Image preview container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="image_preview_container" id="qv_preview">

    <img id="img_zoom" data-zoom-image="images/qv_large_1.JPG" src="images/qv_img_1.jpg" alt="">

   </div><!--/ .image_preview_container-->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of image preview container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Prodcut thumbs carousel - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
   <div class="product_preview" data-output="#qv_preview">

    <div class="owl_carousel" id="thumbnails">
    
     <img src="images/qv_thumb_1.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_1.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_2.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_2.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_3.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_3.jpg" alt="">

     <img src="images/qv_thumb_4.jpg" data-large-image="images/qv_img_4.jpg" alt="">

    </div><!--/ .owl-carousel-->

   </div><!--/ .product_preview-->
   
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of prodcut thumbs carousel - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Share - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
   <div class="v_centered">

    <span class="title">Share this:</span>

    <div class="addthis_widget_container">
     <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
     <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
     <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
     <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
     </div>
     <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of share - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </div>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product image column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product description column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <div class="single_product_description">

   <h3><a href="#">Ivory Body Wash, Original 24 fl oz</a></h3>

   <div class="description_section v_centered">

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product rating - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   
    <ul class="rating">

     <li class="active"></li>
     <li class="active"></li>
     <li class="active"></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>

    </ul>
     
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product rating - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Reviews menu - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

    <ul class="topbar">

     <li><a href="#">3 Review(s)</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Add Your Review</a></li>

    </ul>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of reviews menu - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   </div>

   <div class="description_section">

    <table class="product_info">

     <tbody>

      <tr>

       <td>Manufacturer: </td>
       <td><a href="#">Chanel</a></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

       <td>Availability: </td>
       <td><span class="in_stock">in stock</span> 20 item(s)</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

       <td>Product Code: </td>
       <td>PS06</td>

      </tr>

     </tbody>

    </table>

   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="description_section">

    <p>Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget, elementum vel, cursus eleifend, elit. Aenean auctor wisi et urna.</p>

   </div>

   <hr>

   <p class="product_price"><s>$9.99</s> <b class="theme_color">$5.99</b></p>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="description_section_2 v_centered">
    
    <span class="title">Size:</span>

    <div class="custom_select min">
    <select id="size" >
    <option id="def" value="default" selected>select a course</option>
    <option id="mth" data-price="100" value="1">1 kg</option>
    <option id="eng" data-price="200" value="2">2 kg</option>
    <option id="chm" data-price="300" value="3">3 kg</option>
    <option id="phy" data-price="400" value="4">4 kg</option>
</select>

    </div>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product size - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="description_section_2 v_centered">
    
    <span class="title">Qty:</span>

    <div class="qty min clearfix">

     <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus">&#45;</button>
      <button class="theme_button" data-direction="minus">&#45;</button>
                <input type="text" value="2" id="qty">
     <button class="theme_button" data-direction="plus">&#43;</button>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of quantity - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

   <div class="buttons_row">

    <button class="button_blue middle_btn">Add to Cart</button>

    <button class="button_dark_grey def_icon_btn middle_btn add_to_wishlist tooltip_container"><span class="tooltip top">Add to Wishlist</span></button>

    <button class="button_dark_grey def_icon_btn middle_btn add_to_compare tooltip_container"><span class="tooltip top">Add to Compare</span></button>

   </div>

   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  </div>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product description column - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

 </div>

</div>

<!--==================================
  End quick view modal window
====================================== -->
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question, where do you want to show the updated value, where is the #show_box, #total_box

Comment: forget about my javascript, please provide the new script. calculated value display in this <p class="product_price"><s>$9.99</s> <b class="theme_color">$5.99</b></p>
section, please help on this, I m new to stackoverflow and development.

Comment: what you want man ??? your script works fine as of now. I have checked it on     http://jsfiddle.net/93g7za23/   if you want to set the value at the desired location you can take a label or span and set the  value in it. if you can write this much of jquery code ,what's the big deal?

Comment: actually my problem is problem is coding working but in quantity input box I used Plus or Minus button to do increase & Decrease value . if I click 2 quantity , it calculating as 1 quantity. if I press minus button, its add 2 value. means quantity values not showing correct value. you can see live site: http://indyadeal.com/supermarket/Baby+%26+Kids+Care/Baby+Bath/3/1054/0

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like this

```js
$('#size').change(function() {
  updateValues();
});

$('#qty').keyup(function() {
  updateValues();
});

function updateValues() {
  var qty = $("#qty").val();
  var price = 0;
  var rate = 0;
  $('#size').find('option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-price')) {
      price = $(this).data('price');
      rate = price * qty;
    } else {
      rate = $(this).filter(":selected").val();
    }
  });
  $('#dispamnt').text(rate);
}

$(".button").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    if (oldValue > 1) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
    }
  }

  $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
  updateValues()
});
```

```css
.inc,
.dec,
.spinner-input {
  float: left
}
.inc,
.dec {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer
}
.spinner-input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="product_price"><s>$9.99</s>  <b class="theme_color" id="dispamnt">$5.99</b>
</p>
<div class="description_section_2 v_centered"> <span class="title">Size:</span>
  <div class="custom_select min">
    <select id="size">
      <option id="def" value="5.99" selected>select a course</option>
      <option id="mth" data-price="100" value="1">1 kg</option>
      <option id="eng" data-price="200" value="2">2 kg</option>
      <option id="chm" data-price="300" value="3">3 kg</option>
      <option id="phy" data-price="400" value="4">4 kg</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="description_section_2 v_centered"> <span class="title">Qty:</span>
  <div class="qty min clearfix">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="dec button">-</div>
      <input id="qty" class="spinner-input" type="text" value="1" />
      <div class="inc button">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```